How do I output the label name in a dendrogram in R?
I'm trying to run a cluster analysis for a card sort with the following code.
> compare <- function(x1, x2) {
+     x3 <- x1 + x2
+     ints <- sum(x3 > 1)
+     uno <- sum(x3 > 0)
+     return (ints / uno)
+ }
> getJaccard <- function(data) {
+     l = length(data[1,])
+     jmatrix <- matrix(nrow=l,ncol=l)
+     for (i in 1:l) {
+         for (j in i:l) {
+             s <- compare(data[i], data[,j])
+             jmatrix[i,j] <- s
+             jmatrix[j,i] <- s
+         }
+     }
+     return (jmatrix)
+ }
> cardsort <- function(file="~/Downloads/cardsort_data2.csv", blocks) {
+     filedata <- read.table(file="~/Downloads/cardsort_data2.csv", header=T, sep=",")
+     data <- getJaccard(filedata)
+     colnames(data) <- colnames(filedata)
+     hc <- hclust(dist(t(data)), method="ward.D")
+     hc$labels <- colnames(data)
+     plot(hc, main = Sys.time())
+     rect.hclust(hc, k=blocks, border="red")
+ }

> cardsort("~/Downloads/cardsort_data2.csv", 6)`

My csv data looks like this table of data, with card numbers labelled and groupings on the columns.
When I use this csv data, I get the error "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

When I remove the labels from my csv, my output looks like this dendrogram_output, but instead of the card numbers, the labels are "x1, x2, xn ...."
How do I get the dendrogram to show the card numbers, and what am I doing wrong to receive the non-numeric argument to binary op error?
I removed the labels from the csv to only have numeric values, and I get the dendrogram, but no labels.
When I keep the labels, I get the error FUN(left,right)
EDIT: This is the output I want (I photoshopped this):
dendrogram with row names as labels

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images

Inside the cardsort function, remove the line colnames(data) <- colnames(filedata) and replace hc$labels <- colnames(data) with hc$labels <- colnames(filedata). Let me know if it works.

@MarcoSandri thanks for your suggestion. Tried your suggestion but still receiving Error in FUN(left, right): non-numerical argument to binary operator I'm at a lost >_<

@MarcoSandri 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  31 variables:  $ Group_Card: chr  "Group1" "Group2" "Group3" "Group4" ...  $ Card1     : int  5 1 0 1 0 129 0 0 7 23  $ Card2     : int  0 0 25 0 3 3 0 0 105 28  $ Card3     : int  136 0 0 57 0 0 0 0 5 0  $ Card4     : int  0 0 46 3 0 0 0 0 0 148  $ Card5     : int  1 0 0 1 1 6 187 0 0 1  $ Card6     : int  0 154 0 11 0 0 3 18 0 0
sorry, not sure how to format in a comment

I notice that in your filedata data frame, there is a character string variable called Group_Card. This variable should not be included in the calculations. Thus, you should insert the command filedata <- filedata[,-1] before data <- getJaccard(filedata).

@MarcoSandri you are an angel! This worked! Ah no wonder, I should've removed that label from the original csv!  THANK YOU
